# python date appears in last year

Tags: python

How do I do a check in python that a date appears in the last year. i.e. date between now and (now-1 year)

Thanks

Comment: The Python documentation is quite good and offers a lot examples: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Comment: What is the type of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for leap years:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> today = date.today()
>>> date(today.year - 1, today.month, today.day) < date(2009, 06, 05) <= today
True
>>> date(today.year - 1, today.month, today.day) < date(2009, 06, 04) <= today
False
>>> date(today.year - 1, today.month, today.day) < date(2010, 07, 04) <= today
False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [10]: today=datetime.date.today()

In [11]: datetime.date(2010,5,5) < today
Out[11]: True

In [12]: today-datetime.timedelta(days=365) <= datetime.date(2010,5,5) < today
Out[12]: True

In [13]: today-datetime.timedelta(days=365) <= datetime.date(2009,5,5) < today
Out[13]: False
```

Edit: if `today` is the leap year `2000-2-29`, then `today-datetime.timedelta(days=365)` is `1999-3-1`. If you'd like one year ago to be `1999-2-28` then you could use

```
def add_years(date,num):
    try:
        result=datetime.date(date.year+num,date.month,date.day)
    except ValueError:
        result=datetime.date(date.year+num,date.month,date.day-1)
    return result

today=datetime.date(2000,2,29)
print(add_years(today,-1))
# 1999-02-28
```

Comment: can i put datetime.timedelta(year=1) as some years will be 366 days with the leap year

Comment: @John: No you can't, read the documentation. The signature is *datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])* Does one day matter that much?